# setting up Ruby Koans

Tags: ruby, linux, command-line, autotest, ubuntu

This question is probably pretty stupid/n00bish/inappropriate/localised/sparkly cake, so downvote all you like as long as I get the answer, as I wish very much to be able to go through the koans. :)

I am trying to get [this](http://blog.llamarada.net/?p=1142) to work. (GitHub is [here](https://github.com/renemendoza/ruby_koans)) I've downloaded and extracted it, and the folder is in my Documents directory (I renamed it ruby_koans from the default name). I've been messing around with this all day and can't get it to run in Konsole. :/

I use

```
cd /home/sophia/Documents
```

to move to the directory Documents, which contains the ruby_koans file.

I have no idea what to do after that, as Rake seems to be broken, and I probably installed [Autotest](http://ph7spot.com/musings/getting-started-with-autotest) incorrectly :S

And, before posting here, I already asked #ruby and #kubuntu on freenode. ._.

Comment: What doesn't work, autotest or the koans themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install the koans from http://rubykoans.com/
They have detailed installation instructions and a troubleshooting section.

If for some reason things still don't work properly, then you should seek help from a real-life programmer friend who has done this before :)

**old answer:**

Please, try to run the "path_to_enlightenment.rb" file inside the "koans" directory.

```
cd koans
ruby path_to_enlightenment.rb
```

That doesn't use rake. If that doesn't work, then your ruby installation may be broken.

The first line of the "path_to_enlightenment" is:

```
LOAD_PATH << File.dirname(__FILE__).
```

This makes "require" look for files in the current directory.
Perhaps `File.dirname(__FILE__)` does not return the proper value(for some reason).
Try and replace `File.dirname(__FILE__)` with the absolute path of the directory in which the koans are. I.e. "/home/MYUSERNAME/ruby_koans/koans/".
If I had to guess, I'd say the problem is that the "Documents" folder has an uppercase D in it. You can also try and move the project somewhere else.

Comment: @x10 , <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- about_asserts (LoadError);;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;sophia@sophia-EP45-UD3R:~/Documents/ruby_koans/koans$ ls
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;about_array_assignment.rbabout_array_assignment.rb .. triangle.rb ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; so the files exist -_-

Comment: See the modified answer above :)

Comment: Don't worry, things will get better :) I'm gonna modify my answer once more with this link: http://rubykoans.com/

Comment: @x10, I'll try the rename thing that you point out in your answer, but the main reason to use the download I'm trying to use is syntax highlighting and Autotest capability, which is supposed to make it simpler for me, if I know how to use Autotest :P

Comment: @x10, oh also, where in heaven's name is LOAD_PATH << File.dirname(__FILE__). in path_to_enlightenment.rb? this is the pastebin of the contents of said file, or am i missing something?: http://pastebin.com/aK4tcRmA

Comment: Aaaaaaah. I see. So that's where the problem is :)

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/renemendoza/ruby_koans/blob/master/koans/path_to_enlightenment.rb :)  You seem to have a bad version of the program :) Try and clone the repository in a new location: `git clone git://github.com/renemendoza/ruby_koans `

Comment: @Sophie: You may want to post error messages in the question, rather than in comments, as it's hard to read error messages within comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone https://github.com/renemendoza/ruby_koans.git
cd ruby_koans/koans
autotest
```

If autotest is not already installed, you'll need to do `gem install autotest`.

Open each script and fill in the correct answers as prompted. When you save changes autotest should rerun and show you the next failing one.

Answer (score 0):

For those that got here after downloading the Koans from the `renmendoza` or `neall` versions of the koans, you'll want to get them from https://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans now.  Be sure to run `rake gen` before starting.